# maven primefaces downloading error: Non-parseable POM

Tags: java, maven, jsf, primefaces

Can I have an updated process on how to download primefaces with maven.

I tried using the process provided by primefaces.org but, I get errors in the pom.xml file.

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ttYY.png)

**This is the description of the error.**

Non-parseable POM C:\Users\phili_000.SHELTON5\Documents\ AVA8\EE\pom.xml: expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...org.primefaces\ua0\ua0\r\n            \ua0\ua0\ua0<a... @26:18)

Misspelled Word

### Turn selected text to property

I have looked for videos and posts that will help me but non seem to work.
I did find a post some were that had the same error message.

This [guy](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5848) was trying to install a framework like I was. Maybe that post will help answer this question.

**What I did**

I copied and pasted:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
    <version>6.0</version>  
</dependency>
```

**That, In this:**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**What I want**
I want an updated process on how to download primefaces with marven.

**FIle: pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>EE</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>EE</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: check if you have extra spaces in pom.xml

Comment: Would formatting the text using netbeans fix that.

Comment: How can you have that error when `org.primefaces` isn't in the POM?

Comment: What would I have to add? Link?

Comment: I don't know what more I can do beside pasted all whole code.

Comment: Can you run a console maven output for the command `mvn install` from your folder application? So we can see what exactly is the error with your POM. You of course will need maven on your path to run it from your console. (windows, linux, whatever)

Comment: I don't know how to do that that. Can I just get a copy of someone's Pom.xml

Comment: Type it yourself instead of copypasting.

Comment: What's the difference

Comment: No additional accidental wrong charachters

Comment: So do I only need to add the dependency to Pom.xml